# Using lpad in regexp_replace

Tags: postgresql

I am Using PostgreSQL 9.5 and have a table with a "area_name" text column of names that have numbered extentions:

```
area_name
----------------
AREA
AREA EXT
AREA EXT 1
AREA EXT 5
AREA EXT 49
AREA EXT 50
```

I want to order the result numerically by extention as shown above.

I have tried using a regexp_replace to lpad the numbers with 0s, but using a length of 4 is adding 2 0s in front of the number regardless of if it is 1 or 2 digits!

```
create table ext_test (
    area_name text
);

insert into ext_test values
  ('AREA'),
  ('AREA EXT'),
  ('AREA EXT 1'),
  ('AREA EXT 5'),
  ('AREA EXT 49'),
  ('AREA EXT 50');

select
    area_name,
    regexp_replace(area_name, ' EXT (\d*)', ' EXT ' || lpad('\1', 4, '0')) as order_result
from ext_test
order by order_result;

area_name    | order_result
------------------------------ 
AREA         | AREA
AREA EXT     | AREA EXT
AREA EXT 1   | AREA EXT 001
AREA EXT 49  | AREA EXT 0049
AREA EXT 5   | AREA EXT 005
AREA EXT 50  | AREA EXT 0050
```

Where am I going wrong with the replace expression?

Comment: I hope you check out my answer. ;) it's substantially easier and faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're trying to format them your question calls for ordering. That's pretty simple. Just keep them as `int`.

> **I want to order the result numerically by extention as shown above.**

Just put in the `ORDER BY` statement.

```
SELECT area_name
FROM ext_test
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN area_name ~ '\d'
    THEN (regexp_matches(area_name, '\d+'))[1]::int
  END NULLS FIRST,
  area_name;

  area_name  
-------------
 AREA
 AREA EXT
 AREA EXT 1
 AREA EXT 5
 AREA EXT 49
 AREA EXT 50
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you execute `regexp_replace(area_name, ' EXT (\d*)', ' EXT ' || lpad('\1', 4, '0'))`
First of all the parameters are being evaluated

`lpad('\1', 4, '0')` becomes `'00\1'`

`' EXT ' || lpad('\1', 4, '0')` becomes `' EXT 00\1'`

Which means the captured groups (the numbers in this case) are going to be preceded by 2 zeros.

---

Your goal can be achieved in 2 phases -

1. Left pad all numbers with X preceding zeros
2. truncate each number to its most right X digits

---

```
select      area_name
           ,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(area_name,'\d+',repeat('0',4) || '\&'),'\d*(\d{4})','\1') as order_result

from        ext_test

order by    order_result
;
```

---

```
+-------------+---------------+
| area_name   | order_result  |
+-------------+---------------+
| AREA        | AREA          |
+-------------+---------------+
| AREA EXT    | AREA EXT      |
+-------------+---------------+
| AREA EXT 1  | AREA EXT 0001 |
+-------------+---------------+
| AREA EXT 5  | AREA EXT 0005 |
+-------------+---------------+
| AREA EXT 49 | AREA EXT 0049 |
+-------------+---------------+
| AREA EXT 50 | AREA EXT 0050 |
+-------------+---------------+
```

---

If you have more than a single number in your text, use this version which is based on `'AREA EXT '` -

```
select      area_name
           ,regexp_replace(regexp_replace(area_name,'(?<=AREA EXT )\d+',repeat('0',4) || '\&'),'(?<=AREA EXT )\d*(\d{4})','\1') as order_result

from        ext_test

order by    order_result
;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

(I added one more row with *AREA TEXT 509*)

It looks you can't reference '\1' from regular to `lpad(` like this. Look below - column o is yours - the result is **00509**, second column has length('\1') *which of course is always two, because `'\1'` is interpreted as text, not as regular expression meta syntax. So I believe what happens is `lpad` interprets first argument as metasyntax, but then substracting length of `'\1'` from second argumet interprets it as *text* => 4-2 is *ALWAYS* 2. So it appends two zeroes to any input.

While this is either bug or not meant usage of SQL functions mixed with regular expression meta syntax, I propose getting a value from regular expression and then use it with sql function. Here column *r* is example. and column *replace* is example of meant output:

```
t=# with p as (select regexp_replace(area_name, ' EXT (\d*)', ' EXT ' || lpad('\1', 4, '0')) o,regexp_replace(area_name,'AREA EXT (\d*)',length('\1')||'.\1'||'.'), area_name,regexp_replace(area_name,'AREA EXT (\d*)','\1') r from ext_test)
select *, length(r),replace(area_name,r,lpad(r,4,'0')) from p;
       o        | regexp_replace |  area_name   |    r     | length |    replace
----------------+----------------+--------------+----------+--------+---------------
 AREA           | AREA           | AREA         | AREA     |      4 | AREA
 AREA EXT       | AREA EXT       | AREA EXT     | AREA EXT |      8 | AREA
 AREA EXT 001   | 2.1.           | AREA EXT 1   | 1        |      1 | AREA EXT 0001
 AREA EXT 005   | 2.5.           | AREA EXT 5   | 5        |      1 | AREA EXT 0005
 AREA EXT 0049  | 2.49.          | AREA EXT 49  | 49       |      2 | AREA EXT 0049
 AREA EXT 0050  | 2.50.          | AREA EXT 50  | 50       |      2 | AREA EXT 0050
 AREA EXT 00509 | 2.509.         | AREA EXT 509 | 509      |      3 | AREA EXT 0509
(7 rows)

Time: 0.519 ms
```

just a proposal - maybe use integers for ordering, like here?:

```
t=# with a as (select *,split_part(area_name,'AREA EXT ',2) s from ext_test) select area_name,case when s='' then 0 else s::int end c from a order by c,area_name;
  area_name  | c
-------------+----
 AREA        |  0
 AREA EXT    |  0
 AREA EXT 1  |  1
 AREA EXT 5  |  5
 AREA EXT 49 | 49
 AREA EXT 50 | 50
(6 rows)

Time: 0.354 ms
```

Comment: This is a simplified example. In the actual data 'AREA' above is hundreds of different names from thousands of records. Sometimes the where clause selects on the beginning of the name and then I can just use:
`order by length(area_name), area_name`
Where my where clause get more complicated there can be multiple area_names in the result so this dosn't work.

Comment: please update your question with more examples then?

Comment: This is enough data to show the problem. The real question is why is the padding not working as expected inside the regexp_replace?

Comment: I don't know how to attract attention on this of particular persons. Whales like Erwin or Craig could answer if this is a bug or you just not meant to use regular meta syntax as argument to SQL functions

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand **why** I wasn't getting the result I expected.

Answer (score 0):

And here is another simple way to achieve your goal

```
select      area_name
           ,substring (area_name,'(?<=AREA EXT )\d+')::int as order_result

from        ext_test

order by    order_result nulls first
           ,area_name
;
```

---

```
+-------------+--------------+
| area_name   | order_result |
+-------------+--------------+
| AREA        | (null)       |
+-------------+--------------+
| AREA EXT    | (null)       |
+-------------+--------------+
| AREA EXT 1  | 1            |
+-------------+--------------+
| AREA EXT 5  | 5            |
+-------------+--------------+
| AREA EXT 49 | 49           |
+-------------+--------------+
| AREA EXT 50 | 50           |
+-------------+--------------+
```