# Postgres regexp_replace, using function on 3rd parameter

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgres 9.4, is it possible to apply a function on the captured match?

Example: upper case only the string which are surrounded by double-quotes.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
  '123, "name", ignored~me, "Beer & Cheese", pi=3.14',
  '"(.+?)"', 
  upper('"\1"'),
  'g'
);

--Result  : '123, "name", ignored~me, "Beer & Cheese", pi=3.14'
--Expected: '123, "NAME", ignored~me, "BEER & CHEESE", pi=3.14'
```

It looks like the function appearing in the 3rd parameter of `regexp_replace` is ignored. Is there anyway to use a function and passing the \n group capture as input argument?

Answer (score 0):

I once had [same question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/163579/using-regexp-substitution-part-in-postgres-string-functions), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106960/using-lpad-in-regexp-replace)

I did not get the answer, but general impression that you are not supposed to use SQL functions on arguments of regular expression functions...

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, functions aren't first-class. They can't be passed. There is no part of the language that's interpreted either. It's declarative, compiled (with an optimizer), and evaluated strictly.

Keep in mind, under normal circumstance an update to any column requires rewriting the whole row (not just the column).

You can still accomplish this I would just be looking to a slightly smarter tool for it..

- [`PL/Perl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html)
- [`PL/v8`](https://github.com/plv8/plv8)

Here is an example with `plperl`,

```
CREATE LANGUAGE plperl;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION perl_dynamic_eval_regexp_replace( IN str text, IN pattern text, IN replacementPerl text, OUT text )
STRICT
AS $BODY$
    my ($input, $pattern, $replacement) = @_;
    $input =~ s/$pattern/eval $replacement/ge;
    return $input;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plperl
VOLATILE;


SELECT perl_dynamic_eval_regexp_replace(
  '123, "name", ignored~me, "Beer & Cheese", pi=3.14',
  '"(.+?)"', 
  $$uc("$1")$$
);
```

Comment: Thanks. The upper() was to illustrate the idea. I may need more elaborate function. For example how to write in Perl the equivalence of `regexp_replace(origtxt, '\n', '\\n')`? Also the Perl module is not installed in our server. Not sure if the infrastructure team would be OK to install it.

Comment: It's a trusted language that's packaged by PostgreSQL, it should be relatively easy to get it approved. It's available with every major distro. To replace all newlines with `\n`, which is what I assume you want to do.. Just tell it that: `perl_dynamic_eval_regexp_replace(x, E'\n', '"\\n"')` `E''` tells PostgreSQL to replace the string `"\n"` with a newline, and then you just have to do it in reverse in perl because you're feeding the sequence to `eval`. So `eval "\\n"` returns the `"\n"` string and that's what you want.

Comment: `plv8` is also trusted, fyi. But it's an extension module not maintained by PostgreSQL